# Android Font Recognition API

Tags: android

I'm planning to develop an android font recognition app for my final year project. are there any free APIs that I can use for this process of image recognition. (looking for an API which will take the image as an input and output the name of the font or something similar) please suggest me a solution, I'm new to the android platform.

Comment: There are a couple of websites that allow you to input an image and (after inputting some characters by hand) give back suggestions of what the font could be; e.g. [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and [What Font is](http://www.whatfontis.com/). Both don't seem to have a public API, both WTF does have an iOS and Android app you can potentially learn from. Do make sure you carefully read the terms and conditions etc.

Answer (score 0):

[I would try OpenCV, which has quite useful libraries and examples](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)